# torchvision.transforms.RandomRotation fill argument not working

Tags: python, pytorch, data-augmentation, torchvision

I am working on tensors and want to rotate them with `torchvision.transforms.RandomRotation` and use the `fill` option.

```py
import torch
import torchvision

img1 = torch.rand((1, 16, 16))
img2 = torchvision.transforms.RandomRotation(45, fill=1)(img1)
```

However, I always get:

> Argument fill/fillcolor is not supported for Tensor input. Fill value is zero

and it gets not filled with ones. I have the same problem with `torchvision.transforms.RandomPerspective`.
I am using Python 3.8 and PyTorch 1.7.1. I tried using `fill=(1,)`, which seemed to be a workaround, but it did not worked for me. Do you know what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably using torchvision v0.8.2 or older. This issue was fixed 5 months ago in the [PR #2904](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/pull/2904/files#diff-497b983ae7c82237c4a0722bc6f6637525e0cdf8369dbd78ee19cf986bffe258R854-R862). If you are not using [v0.9.0](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/releases/tag/v0.9.0) or newer, you won't be able to use `fill` in a `Tensor` input :(

So, the only solution is to upgrade your torchvision.

Comment: Unfortunately i am using torchvision.__version__ '0.8.2'.

Comment: @user930958 my mistake. They delayed the deliver and PR #2904 was only incorporated in v0.9.0 (see [changelog](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/releases/tag/v0.9.0)). Therefore, the problem is precisely because you're using an older version.

Comment: Updating pytorch or torchvision via conda did not work, since it updated not to the latest version, which i didn´t notice. However, removing and reinstalling helped.

Answer (score 0):

Newer torch versions have the attribute name as 'fill' while prior to 2.0.0 it was 'fillcolor'